# Build command on Vercel cant find config file in base path

Tags: node.js, npm, vercel, npm-scripts

I am trying to build my project on Vercel and then run a config script to generate my robots.txt file, so my build script is:

```
"build": "docusaurus build && npx generate-robotstxt --config .\\robotstxt.config.js .\\build\\robots.txt",
```

The command works just fine locally, but vercel throws error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '.robotstxt.config.js'
```

If I remove the `.\\`

```
"build": "docusaurus build && npx generate-robotstxt --config \\robotstxt.config.js \\build\\robots.txt",
```

Then I can't build it locally and Vercel still gives me the same error, without the "." now:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'robotstxt.config.js'
```